# setDelegate:self generates a caution flag

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I am trying to learn Objective C and have an error in the code for one of my lessions and I do not know how to solve it.
Code:

```
 //  AppController.m

 #import "AppController.h"

 @implementation AppController

 - (id)init
    {
         [super init];
         speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
         [speechSynth setDelegate:self];
         voiceList = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices] retain];
         Return self;
    }
```

From [speechSynth setDelegate:self]; I get the error: Sending 'AppController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id< NSSpeechSynthesizerDelagate>'. 
The program compiles with a caution flag and seems to run correctly. I have compared my code with the author's code and can find no differences and none of my searches have indicated I should get an error on this line. The book was written for Xcode 3 and I am using Xcode 4.0.2.

Any suggestions or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you implementing the delegate protocol in the header?

Comment: Does your AppController implement the NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xcode is warning you that the `setDelegate` method expects an instance of a class that has implemented the `NSSpeechSynthesizerDelagate` protocol. Now, you have, but you've probably just forgotten to declare that you have. In your class declaration, change

```
@class AppController : NSObject
```

to

```
@class AppController : NSObject<NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>
```

to tell the world "I obey `NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`!", and silence the warning. You never know - you might get warned that you've forgotten to implement some non-optional delegate methods, and save yourself an annoying bug somewhere down the line.

Comment: @adam  Thank you for your answer and the example, that worked. I would never had figured out how to do the coding in that format on my own. It was not in the book nor in the authors on-line examples. I did have the delegate bonded to the tableview so that I could access the voices for speech and thought that was all I needed.

Answer (score 2):

When you cast the self object then warning message disappears.

```
[speechSynth setDelegate:(id < NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate >) self];
```